# Adwords/Anayltics: How can I see conversions statitics based on browser type

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

After a redesign of our site we're facing some conversion loss and I suspect that there's a problem with some browser that Í haven't checked.

Is there any way in analytics or adwords to get conversion statistics based on browser type?

Answer (score 1):

In Analytics, create a "Custom Report" where the number of conversions is the chosen Metric and the browser type is the Dimension.